# Searching for a thesis.

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

In several articles about curves, etc, in Minkowski spaces $\Bbb L^3$ and $\Bbb L^4$, there is

> Walrave, J., Curves and surfaces in Minkowski space. Doctoral Thesis,
>   K.U. Leuven, Fac. of Science, Leuven 1995.

as a reference, but I'm having trouble finding said thesis in the internet. Since it dates from a long time ago, I think that it might not be accesible at all. And I don't even know if the author is still alive, so I could contact him (talking to the author directly worked for me before). Does someone know where to find it? I tried [Library Genesis](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/) and [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/) to no avail. Looking for it, I found [these](http://www.kirj.ee/19784/?tpl=1061&c_tpl=1064) references, but that's not it. I tried looking around at the [university site](http://wet.kuleuven.be/english), but I don't know Dutch.

Is there hope for me?

Comment: Your profile says you are a student. Most major universities have an interlibrary loan service that can go dig up this thesis for you. They will contact the other university on your behalf. Have you checked with them?

Comment: I didn't even think of that. I'll try, thanks!

Comment: May be you could try to send an e-mail to the author: see here http://www.kuleuven.be/wieiswie/en/person/00071044

Comment: Sending an e-mail worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to send prof. Walrave an e-mail. He was very receptive and sent me <strike>[the link for his thesis](http://www.cmmc.be/JohanWalravePhD.pdf)</strike>. I'll leave it here, in case someone studying the subject stumble upon this post, someday.

---

The link was broken. [This one](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AtoD5qd_3E71h07A5ehtH8Dy2bXQ) should work.