# Ph.D thesis by Whitcomb

Tags: reference-request, group-rings

Does somebody has a link to Ph.D thesis by Whitcomb titled "The group ring problem" University of Chicago 1968. It was referred in a paper and I have some things to look up in that. I could not find it on google. If someone knows a link, can you please suggest it to me?

Comment: For something that old, interlibrary loan might be your best option (I've received old Ph.D. theses that way).

Comment: One option is trying to find out his email. I once needed a thesis, the author is still alive, so I sent him an email and he happily sent me the pdf.

Comment: [Try to do something similar.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970902/searching-for-a-thesis)